# Calculate avg for field using data from another table MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2003

I have 3 tables : [image]

`Film.rating` is the average of ratings for that film from the `Rate` table.
In SQL, to calculate film rating I would do:

```
SELECT AVG(Rate.rating)
FROM Rate, Film
WHERE Rate.uidFilm=Film.uidFilm;
```

I do not know how to write this in MS Access and where I should put this (or maybe another?) formula?

**How do I 'connect' Film.rating with the calculation above?** 
In constructor for the `Film` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `GROUP BY` in your query. Try this

```
SELECT Film.Title, AVG(Rate.rating)
FROM Rate
    INNER JOIN Film ON Rate.uidFilm = Film.uidFilm
GROUP BY Film.Title;
```

This should give you the average ratings of all movies with their title.